# rqt_console sorting by order received?

Tags: ros-groovy, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears possible to sort by every column by clicking on them except the order received column (far left).  Sorting by Time does when there are a lot of messages due to the precision of the timer.

Saving to .csv appears to sort by how the console is sorting them, and removing the .config/ros.org/rqt_gui.ini does not reset it.

How do I reset rqt_console to sort by order received?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64241/rqt_console-sorting-by-order-received?/) by [Eruditass](https://answers.ros.org/users/3250/eruditass/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks this was a bug and recently fixed.

---

Originally posted by [Eruditass](https://answers.ros.org/users/3250/eruditass/) with karma: 121 on 2014-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0